# useEffect within a custom hook doesn't rerender on delete

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use hooks and implement a custom hook for handling my data fetching after every update I send to the API.

My custom hook, however, doesn't fire on change like I want it too. Delete has to be clicked twice for it to rerender. Note: I removed some functions from this code as they don't pertain to the question.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
    import {Trash} from 'react-bootstrap-icons'
    import InlineEdit from 'react-ions/lib/components/InlineEdit'

    function Board(){
        const [render, setRender] = useState(false)
        const [boards, setBoards] = useState([]);
        const [isEditing, setEdit] = useState(false)
        const [value, setValue] = useState("")
        const[newValue, setNewValue] = useState("")
        const [error, setError] = useState("")

        function useAsyncHook(setState, trigger) {
            const [result] = useState([]);
            const [loading, setLoading] = useState("false");
            useEffect(() => {
                async function fetchList() {
                    try {
                        setLoading("true");
                        const response = await fetch(
                            `http://localhost:8080/api/boards`
                        );
                        const json = await response.json();
                        setState(json)
                    } catch (error) {
                        //console.log(error)
                        setLoading("null");
                    }
                }
            fetchList()
            }, [trigger]);

            return [result, loading];
        }

        useAsyncHook(setBoards, render)

        const handleDelete = (id) => {
            console.log("delete clicked")
            setLoading(true);
            fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/boards/` + id, {
                method: "DELETE",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
            })
            setRender (!render)
        }

       return(
        <div>
            <ul>

                {boards.map(board => (
                <li key={board.id}>
                        <InlineEdit value={board.size} isEditing={isEditing} changeCallback={(event)=>handleSave (event, board.id)} />
                        <Trash onClick={()=>handleDelete(board.id)}/>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        );

    }

    export default Board
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**OPTION 1:**

Maybe you wanna have a hook that tells you when to fetch the board, right? For example:

```
const [auxToFetchBoard, setAuxToFetchBoard] = useState(false);
```

Then, in a `useEffect` you execute the function `fetchBoard` everytime that hook changes:

```
useEffect(fetchBoard, [auxToFetchBoard]);
```

Finally, in your `handleDelete` function, if your delete request returns correctly, you have to update `auxToFetchBoard`. Something like this:

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError("");

    fetch(yourURL, yourOptions)
        .then(res => {
            // check if response is correct and
            setIsLoading(false);
            setAuxToFetchBoard(!auxToFetchBoard);
        })
        .catch(() => {
            setIsLoading(false);
            setError("Error while deleting stuff");
        });
};
```

Note: I changed the names of `isLoading` and `setIsLoading` because they are more explicit.

**OPTION 2:**

Instead of fetching the board again and again, you can update your board (in this case your code would be in 8th line inside the `handleDelete`function).

Hope it helps.

Comment: that worked, thank you! however, why do I need to pass the trigger (auxToFetchBoard) in square brackets? I'm not sure I understand the syntax

Comment: That's the syntax: the 2nd param is an array. And in this array you can pass more than one var, and the first param function will execute when any of them changes.

Comment: You're welcome! Btw, could you upvote my answer? Thanks.